# Windows Phone Notifications in Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to send a push notification to windows phone 8 devices, however Microsoft official documentation is using a method that no longer exists *SendMpnsNativeNotificationAsync*,  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-phone-get-started/, I only have *SendWindowsNativeNotification* but im not sure if this is for Windows or Windows Phone, right now my code is as follows:

```
            var toast = WindowsNotificationXmlBuilder.CreateToastText01Xml("Hi Rana");
            hubClient.SendWindowsNativeNotification(toast.InnerXml);
```

But im getting a 400 bad request, no Windows target is found, please help.

Rana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the version of ‘Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll’ you are using ? [SendMpnsNativeNotificationAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.notifications.notificationhubclient.sendmpnsnativenotificationasync.aspx) is not deprecated so check for proper version and use this api that should resolve the issue

Comment: I was using an older version for the azure package for the API. Thanks a lot for the heads up.